# Saving html page content (buffer) to .log file

Tags: go, buffer

**I am trying to write a buffer into my .log file to log what the buffer gets.
When I try a string in my logger, it works fine.**

**But when I use my buffer as the string, it's giving me this error:**

```
cannot use content (type *bytes.Reader) as type string in argument
```

**Here is my logger (working fine):**

```
func LogRequestFile(data string) {
// If the file doesn't exist, create it, or append to the file
f, err := os.OpenFile("loggies.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if _, err := f.Write([]byte(data)); err != nil {
    f.Close() // ignore error; Write error takes precedence
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
}
```

**Here is where I am calling the log:**

```
func (p *SomeFunction) FunctionName(buffer []byte) []byte {
if len(buffer) > 0 && p.Payload != "" {
    buffer = bytes.Replace(buffer, []byte("</body>"), []byte("<jamming>"+p.Payload), 1)
}

var content = bytes.NewReader(buffer);
LogRequestFile(content)

return buffer
}
```

**This is the buffer creation:**
[Buffer creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbLNH.png)

Once again, I am wanting to get the content of the page and save it inside a .log file.

As you see:
`buffer = bytes.Replace(buffer, []byte("</body>"), []byte("<jamming>"+p.Payload), 1)`

The above code works to replace a section of the html page.
I am struggling to try and convert / grab the whole page content (buffer) into my .log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it appears it was my eyes being stupid.
I changed to this now it works.

```
func (p *SomeFunction) FunctionName(buffer []byte) []byte {

if len(buffer) > 0 && p.Payload != "" {
    log.Debugf(" -- Injecting JS [%s] \n", p.Payload)
    buffer = bytes.Replace(buffer, []byte("</body>"), []byte("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>"+p.Payload+"</script></body>"), 1)
    buffer = bytes.Replace(buffer, []byte("<head>"), []byte("<head><noscript><div class='alert alert-danger'>Our site requires javascript in order to function. Please enabled it and refresh the page.</div></noscript>"), 1)
}

LogRequestFile(buffer)

return buffer

}

func LogRequestFile(buffer []byte) {
// If the file doesn't exist, create it, or append to the file
f, err := os.OpenFile("loggies.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if _, err := f.Write([]byte(buffer)); err != nil {
    f.Close() // ignore error; Write error takes precedence
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
}
```